# How to generate token to reset password in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC project and also including password recovery, when users forget the password, they can reset it. I am able to send email for password reset, but after trying to reset password on `resetpassword.cshtml` I get an error that says "Invalid Token"

**These are my action methods in the account controller.**

```
    // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> 
    ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email,  
        Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,   
         model.Email);

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new 
       System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
                new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", 
        "Reset Password"),
                new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(model.Email));
            m.Subject = "Reset Password";



            string code = user.Id;

            m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0}<BR/>Please reset your
         password by clicking the following link: <a href=\"{1}\"   
         title=\"User Email Confirm\">{1}</a>", user.UserName, 
       Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id,  
           code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme));


            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new    
          System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

            smtp.Credentials = new  
          System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", 
           "mypassword");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(m);




            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", 
      "Account", new { Email = user.Email });

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
       }



    //
    // GET: /Account/ResetPassword

       [AllowAnonymous]

       public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
       {
        return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
       }


    //
    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel
      model)
        {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", 
        "Account");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, 
         model.Code, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation",  
         "Account");
          }
          AddErrors(result);
          return View();
         }
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: Put a break in the `ResetPassword` method on the line where you call  `ResetPasswordAsync`. Can you get past that point to see if the result was a success?

Comment: How to put a break? can you elaborate?

Comment: Put a break as in a debug-break.

Comment: Can you please post your `resetpassword.cshtml`

Answer (score 0):

I am kinda having the same issue, but I want to be able to reset passwords with user's usernames (i changed from email to usernames)

var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

Here you are using FindByNameAsync(), change it to FindByEmailAsync()